# how can I make a ASCII string in Python3 or 2.7 with unicode_literals

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I cannot use telnet with Python3 or "from **future** import unicode_literals"

I know what the error is, but how to I make an old fashioned (i think ascii) string

Thanks

Comment: Other than encoding?

Comment: Please provide minimal code illustrating the issue.

Comment: Telnet is, by definition, 7bit ASCII and anything with the high bit set is basically the control channel.  Trying to encode/decode anything other than ASCII would be problematic at best.  Do you maybe mean [Unicode equivalence or normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization)?

Comment: thanks for this information, i am slowly getting it

i must admit i was using 2.7 forward compatible recommendation here, i assumed therefore i had the problem on Python3 (and did not test this)

on the documentation i found to add:
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

this is still on the document actually, the answer from bobince says i should use it

thanks for the information, it puts my mind at rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to I make an old fashioned (i think ascii) string

Use the backported Python 3 syntax: `b'some byte string'`.

However.

**Never use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.**

This feature was a [mistake](https://lists.gt.net/python/dev/1292881).

Comment: thanks very much, on the documentation i'd been following, i was trying to be forward compatible with the string:

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

at least now i know i can be mostly forward compatible, it says they returned the u"this is unicode" thing in python3

thanks so much for the answer